# change date format in R including the day

Tags: r, date

I have a `data table` that contains the dates in this format:`8/11/2016` 
I would like to change this date format to that one: `Sunday, September 11, 2016`.
Is there a quick and dirty way to do that ?

Comment: See the `?strftime` help page. The fact that you are using data.table doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 3):

```
#create the variable 

x <- as.Date('08/11/2016','%m/%d/%Y')

# convert to the desired format

as.character(x, '%A, %B %d, %Y')


 # more about that here 
# http://www.statmethods.net/input/dates.html
```

Answer (score 1):

```
importDate <- as.Date('08/11/2016','%m/%d/%Y')

# format it to desired format
format(importDate, "%A %B %d %Y")
```

You can have list of more format possible on :
https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/strptime.html